# PHP IF statement testing decoded JSON data

Tags: php, json, webhooks, php-curl

I want to send received JSON data to a PHP CURL script I've written on my server to then forward the data to multiple external webhook URLs conditioned on data received in a specific field key/value.

However, either my IF statement is misconfigured or I'm not accessing the field data properly, because my test webhook endpoint isn't being delivered to. If I remove the IF statement, the code delivers the data as expected.

```
$dataReceive = file_get_contents("php://input");
$dataEncode = json_encode($dataReceive, true);
$headers = array ( 'Content-type: application/json');
print_r($dataEncode);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataEncode);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

if ( $dataEncode ['Field 3'] == 'Test' )  {
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://webhook1.com');
 }
if ($dataEncode ['Field 3'] == 'Test Value 2' ) {
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://webhook2.com');
 }

$results = curl_exec($curl);
echo $results;
curl_close($curl);
```

The JSON data received in the $dataReceive object is:

```
{
   "Timestamp": 1568838624687,
   "Object": "Project",
   "UserId": "",
   "ObjectId__PhaseId": 111,
   "Other__PhaseName": "Turndown",
   "ProjectId": 111,
   "OrgId": 111,
   "Event": "PhaseChanged",
   "ObjectId__ProjectTypeId": 1409
 }
```

I'm testing by using Postman to just send dummy data to my PHP script, but once that works as expected, I'll actually be filtering for the key "Other_PhaseName".

Appreciate the help!

Comment: `json_encode()` should be `json_decode()`.

Comment: `$dataReceive ['Field 3' == 'Test' ]`? Pretty sure that's now what you want there.

Comment: That should be `if ($dataEncode['field 3'] == 'Test'(`

Comment: Thanks, fixed on both points and updated my question...data still not delivering

Comment: @tommycopeland could you show what's inside the `$dataEncode`, since you said it is what caused the IF statements to fails

Comment: @HastaDhana, I've updated my post to answer your question...thanks!

Comment: @tommycopeland have you tried `json_decode()`? also there are no `'Field 3'` index within that json data

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with the if statements. It should be like this

```
if ( $dataEncode['Field 3'] == 'Test' )  {
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://webhook1.com');
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both, I fixed the IF statement and I set it to `$dataEncode`, still not hitting the webhook. I've confirmed it does work as expected if I remove the IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few errors in there.

Start with your if statements

```
if ( $dataEncode['Field 3'] == 'Test')  {
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://webhook1.com');
 }

if ($dataEncode['Field 3'] == 'Test Value 2'){
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://webhook2.com');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that...still no dice.